# Combinations of the letters of a word?

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

In how many ways can the letters of the word CHROMATIC be arranged,

find the probability that the string of letters begins with the letter M

I don't understand how to single out M so the possibilities would only begin with M?

Comment: Place $M$ in front and keep it there. The rest of the letters will be placed after $M$ in some order, resulting in something like $MXXXXXXXX$. How many ways can the other letters be placed (think permutations of the other letters)?

Comment: ...and don't forget that there are repeated letters!

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods.

As joeb states, you can compare the size of the favoured event to the sample space by [counting arrangements of all the letters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176973/in-how-many-ways-can-the-letters-of-the-word-chromatic-be-arranged).

Alternatively, only the placement of the letter $M$ is relevant.   The arrangement of the other eight letters among themselves is independent of this.

If you are not *required* to count arrangements before finding the probability, the second method is much more direct.

---

Method 1(a): Count ways to place $M$ in first place, then arrange the remaining $8$ symbols of which exactly $2$ are identical.  Compare to the count of ways to arrange all $9$ symbols of which exactly $2$ are identical.

Method 1(b): Count ways to place $M$ in first place, then arrange the remaining $8$ individual symbols (treating them as distinct).  Compare to the count of ways to arrange all $9$ individual symbols (treating them likewise).

Method 2: Count the ways to place $M$ in first place.  Compare to ways to place $M$ in any of the $9$ positions.  The remaining letters are irrelevant.

Comment: So would this be C(9,1) = 9 and then 9*9 =81

Comment: Think more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the number of ways to arrange the letters of CHROATIC, as you have the M already given.

Comment: The number of ways to arrange this would be 8!/2! = 20,160